# How to throw an exception without an if construct

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have created a method that checks if there is an element in the list with a specific id, and if it does not exist it throws an exception. I just do not know how to check if the `match` value is `false`, then throw an my exception AccessToMessageForbiddenException.

```
private void validMessage(Long messageId) {
    List<Message> messageList = messageService.findBySender(1L);
    messageList.addAll(messageService.findByRecipient(1L));

    boolean match = messageList.stream().anyMatch(v -> messageId.equals(v.getId()));

    //How to throw an exception without an if construct
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with using an if statement?

Comment: Why can't you use an if statement ?

Comment: what about try catch?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `findAny()` instead of `anyMatch`, and throw an exception if the resulting `Optional` is empty.

This doesn't require an if statement. Just use [orElseThrow()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-), which throws an exception if the `Optional` is empty:

```
private void validMessage(Long messageId) {
    List<Message> messageList = messageService.findBySender(1L);
    messageList.addAll(messageService.findByRecipient(1L));

    messageList.stream()
               .filter(v -> messageId.equals(v.getId()))
               .findAny()
               .orElseThrow(AccessToMessageForbiddenException::new);
}
```

Comment: _**if** the resulting Optional is empty._ You said if! :-)

Comment: @Eran +1, but `orElseThrow` is still an if statement - internally. still this is much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You can get an optional of the Stream and use a consumer to throw an exception

```
Consumer<Message> d = t -> {
        throw new CustomException("Message: " + Message.toString());
 };


messageList.stream().filter(yourFilterPredicate).findAny().ifPresent(d);
```